# Determining configurations between planes.

Tags: geometry

I have trouble determining the geometric configurations between planes, when the  3 planes don't have a unique solution. The question may have been asked, however, there weren't any comprehensive answers

Comment: Consider the dimensions of pairwise intersections.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but could you please elaborate on the method?